# Update multiple rows with different values in a single query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a General Ledger Table in a database (SQL Server 2005), With columns (ID, Insertion_Date, Invoice_No, Debit, Credit and Balance).

When a user add some entries, he will be given to fill the invoice no. and amount(Debit) so Balance will automatically be added as Balance = Balance - Amount. Anyway, after having multiple rows for the same invoice, the user decided to edit the amount for a previous row. After editing the amount, the balance of the same row and the other rows should change automatically. (As: the edited row will take the new amount like: Balance = Balance - newamount, and the other rows will take the new balance and sub. with their current amount).

Example: Table GL

```
ID   Date       Invoice_No    Debit    Credit    Balance
---------------------------------------------------------
1   19/3/2014    123456        0        400        400
2   19/3/2014    123456       100         0        300
3   20/3/2014    123456        50         0        250
4   21/3/2014    123456       100         0        150
5   22/3/2014    123456        50         0        100
```

After Editing the row with ID 2 and making the change on the Debit Column (instead of 100 making it 50) only, The other rows will be effected so the result should look like this.

```
ID   Date       Invoice_No    Debit    Credit    Balance
---------------------------------------------------------
1   19/3/2014    123456        0        400        400
2   19/3/2014    123456        50         0        350
3   20/3/2014    123456        50         0        300
4   21/3/2014    123456       100         0        200
5   22/3/2014    123456        50         0        150
```

Any Idea how can I manage this with a single query. Am new at SQL and need help. Please ask for more Info. if needed.

Comment: You shoud tag this as sql too ...

Comment: consider to use a trigger for this. When you update some amount, the trigger update every other row

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 7):

I would STRONGLY advise you NOT to keep a "running total" as a field in the transaction table - calculate it in a view, stored procedure, or in the consuming application.  Otherwise a change to one record will cascade to potentially every other record in the table.

Comment: Excellent advice.  The OP might also consider making `Debit` and `Credit` into one column containing positive/negative values as appropriate.  This might be a bit off topic, though...

Comment: Actually, I am doing it in a stored procedure, but I stopped at this point currently.

Comment: Doing what?  Calculating the running balance?  Your question indicates that it's a field in the physical table.

Comment: I did the stored procedure for a simple update process not the running balance. Planning to add this operation to the stored procedure if possible.

Comment: Putting the update in a sproc doesn't make it any better - you're still cascading one update to multiple records.  DON'T store the running balance - CALCULATE it when you GET the data.